# SSO Integration with jenkins from crowd is not working

Tags: cookies, jenkins, single-sign-on, jira, atlassian-crowd

I have configured crowd server for centralized Login for my stack-hold applications like (Jira, Bitbucket, Jenkins.. etc..) so basically architecture is like this.

[image]

Jenkins crowd2 plugin configuration looks like this
[image]

and the cookie name for token is as same as jira (cookie.token_key)

my crowd.property file looks like this

```
application.name                        crowd
application.password                    password
application.login.url                   http://MYCROWDIP:8095/crowd/console/

crowd.server.url                        http://MYCROWDIP:8095/crowd/services/
crowd.base.url                          http://MYCROWDIP:8095/crowd/

session.isauthenticated                 session.isauthenticated
session.tokenkey                        session.tokenkey
session.validationinterval              2
session.lastvalidation                  session.lastvalidation
```

Centralized login is working, but SSO is not working. I mean if i login to jenkins and if i open jira it is not logging in automatically with the same user. Where am i going wrong.

Extra: I am inspecting the network of both jenkins login and jira login and i found `cookie.token_key` seems different in both jenkins and jira.

Where am i going wrong ?

Comment: Hi Prabhu, Above problem solved? If yes could you tell me the steps that  you followed to configre SSO for Jenkins with Crowd.

Comment: I have the same issue. but the cookie.token_key (crowd.toke_key) is the same for each request/browser tab, but still it asks for login each time. And it's the same for Jira/Confluence also

Comment: Found the issue. In my case it was due to the used proxy (we had HAProxy) and changed to Apache which also resolved the SSO issue